# Full-Text Search on VARBINARY - viewing the actual text content

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search, sql-server-2016, full-text-indexing

I'm experimenting with SQL Server full-text search on binary documents such as pdf, doc, docx, rtf. SQL Server seems to be able to read the text perfectly as I've succeeded in getting expected search results for text searches inside the `VARBINARY` column.

My problem is that I don't know how to see what SQL sees: how can I read the plain-text extracted from the docs?

So far I've done the following:

1. Install Adobe `IFilter`
2. Install SSMSBoost so I can more easily view VARBINARY data from SSMS results for debugging
3. Enabled Full-Text

```sql
-- 1. Check SQL Full-Text Feature Enabled
select serverproperty('IsFullTextInstalled') AS IsFullTextInstalled

-- 2. Refresh Full-Text document_type Filters from the Operating System
EXEC sp_fulltext_service @action='load_os_resources', @value=1;
EXEC sp_fulltext_service @action='verify_signature', @value=0;

-- 3. Check SQL recognises the document types
SELECT *
FROM sys.fulltext_document_types
where document_type IN ('.rtf', '.doc', '.pdf', '.docx')
```

4. Initialised table with full-text search

```sql
CREATE TABLE Files.Content
(
    id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    content VARBINARY(MAX),
    extension VARCHAR(10)
);

ALTER TABLE Files.Content 
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_content 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id);

-- INIT FULL-TEXT INDEXES
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG FTC; 

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX 
ON Files.Content (content TYPE COLUMN extension LANGUAGE 1033)
KEY INDEX PK_content ON FTC
WITH 
    CHANGE_TRACKING = AUTO, 
    STOPLIST=OFF -- For now, will probably turn on later
;
```

5. Imported VARBINARY column in SQL Server, using SSIS. 40 sample files averaging 200KB with a total of 30MB
6. Tested a full-text search query and verified the document results are correct using SSMSBoost.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM [Files].[Content]
WHERE CONTAINS(content, 'some search') ;
```

But I can't seem actually get any text content out. I want to see a column with text in the files, and not just the binary content. This seems like it should be trivial, as SQL is getting the text in order to search it. Nothing of apparent relevance is coming up on Google.

I do know I can use other methods to get the text out - various solutions exist in C#, Powershell, Node.js and these can be wrapped into SSIS packages / SQL Jobs - but this seems overkill when the text must exist somewhere under the hood in SQL Server.

Is there a T-SQL way to get at it? I'm using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: You may be misunderstanding how full-text searching works. SQL Server outsources the problem of extracting text from the file(s) to a separate process that provides a pile of index references in return. At no point does the database have access to a textual representation of the document. Have a look at [IFilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFilter) and [Full-Text Search processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15#processing).

Comment: @HABO yes, I think you're right about my misunderstanding! I'm now trying to get IFilter to work inside an SSIS Script Task instead...  it's not going well! :-|

Answer (score 0):

You can query [`sys.dm_fts_index_keywords`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-fts-index-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Returns information about the content of a full-text index for the
> specified table.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords(DB_ID('MyDB'), OBJECT_ID('Files.Content'))
```